# Android Failed to unparcel Bitmap error on Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an application that allows the user to go to the photo gallery and select a photo to use as an avatar. The code works fine everywhere except for the Xoom, which fires up the gallery, allows the user to select the photo and then fails with a "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to unparcel Bitmap". I'm using the following method to call for the gallery:

```
public Intent getImagePickerIntent(int width, int height) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("outputX", width);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", height);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
    intent.putExtra("setWallpaper", false);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    return intent;
}
```

And then I'm getting the Bitmap data out using the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == PHOTO_PICKED) {
        // If the activity successfully captured a photo
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data.getExtras() != null) {
            // Resize photo to 100x100 and then save to user's device
            try {
                // putting this in a try-catch after seeing odd exceptions on a Xoom
                ImageHelper.save(PrefsActivity.this, MyApplication.DEVICE_PHOTO_FILE_NAME, ImageHelper.resize((Bitmap)data.getExtras().getParcelable("data"), 100, 100));
```

Note that I'm getting the Bitmap by calling `(Bitmap)data.getExtras().getParcelable("data")`

This works fine on Android 2.3 and below, Any idea why it is failing in 3.x?

**EDIT**: To make it more exciting, this same code works fine on Honeycomb in a regular Activity. This particular issue is occurring in a PreferencesActivity.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently encountered a similar issue while attempting to return a Bitmap in an onActivityResult method.  Inexplicably, the following code works on SDK 3, but fails on anything greater:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();                 
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("someImage");
```

As a work around, I converted the bitmap into a byte array in the activity called with startActivityForResult:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);            
intent.putExtra( "myByteArray", stream.toByteArray() );
```

Once back in the onActivityResult, I retrieve it with:

```
byte[] myByteArray = intent.getExtras().getByteArray("myByteArray");
```

I then convert back into a Bitmap with the following:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(myByteArray);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

I hope this helps someone.